# Minikube start command gives Template parsing error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I was playing around with [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) and [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) and I used the `minikube stop` & `minikube delete` commands. After this I was unable to start minikube again resulting in the following error:

```
* minikube v1.11.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Using the docker driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: provision: get ssh host-port: get port 22 for "minikube": docker container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exit status 1
stdout:


stderr:
Template parsing error: template: :1:4: executing "" at <index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0>: error calling index: index of untyped nil

* Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
* Failed to start docker container. "minikube start" may fix it: driver start: expected container state be running but got "Stopped"
*
X error provisioning host: Failed to start host: driver start: expected container state be running but got "Stopped"
*
* minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

I tried starting Minikube again with both `minikube start` and `minikube start --driver=docker`. It resulted in the same error. So I tried to remove the Minikube docker image, but Docker wasn't working out anymore as well, it gave me the following error with *every* docker command:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.40/containers/json: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1651#issuecomment-363777629) answer which solved the Docker related error , open [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) and execute:

`KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config`

This will tell Minikube to look at that folder for the configuration. **Note** that this environment variable is an extention of the `$HOME` environment variable. Check if this variable is correctly pointing towards `%USERPROFILE%`, check in Git Bash via `echo $HOME`.

After these both variables are set correctly my docker commands were working again.

Then I ran the following commands as advised [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8163#issuecomment-636382949) to start the minikube cluster again without any problems:

1. `docker system prune`
2. `minikube delete`
3. `minikube start --driver=docker`